# JPA commit() after persist() : Required or Not

Tags: java, jpa, transactions

I am working an a JPA 2.0 project, where I am saving my `Entity` class objects like :-

```
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    UserTransaction userTrans = (UserTransaction) 
    ctx.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_NAME);
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    User user = new User("ankit","nigam",25);
    em.persist(user); // persisted in db after this executes
    userTrans.commit(); // whether it is required OR not.
```

So whether I am using  `userTrans.commit()` or not, my `user` object is getting saved in Db, after `persist()` executes. But some of my colleagues say, as a standard we should `commit()` the transaction.

What should be the approach which I follow and whats the logic behind `commit()` and `persist()`. Please throw some lights.

Comment: Any updates. No one is having any clues ?

Comment: @user403348255 how to check the autocommit status. i am using DB2

Comment: a transaction has to be committed one way or another, either autocommit, or Spring managing your transactions and committing it, or JavaEE managing your transaction and committing, or you committing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is autocommit ON in your DB? If it is then that is the reason why the changes get permanently stored in your DB irrespective of whether or not you commit the transaction from your application. In production the autocommit is generally set OFF because it hampers the performance/response time of the DB, that is why developers are generally encouraged to control the commit or rollback of a transaction from their application. The link details the command to handle autocommit in db2:  http://www.db2util.com/administration/options-db2-command-line-disable-autocommit/